# Use a variable before its declaration

Tags: python, conditional-statements, declaration

I am writing a Python script and I have a problem of variable declaration, here is a part of my script :

```
if chromosome :
    if chromosome.group(1) != '1' :
        output.close()
        print str(base)+" bases found in chromosome "+chr_name
        chr_name = chromosome.group(1)
    output = open(current_dir+"/"+name+"3/"+name+".chr"+chromosome.group(1)+".wig", "w")
    output.write("fixedStep chrom=chr"+chromosome.group(1)+" start=1 step=1\n")
```

As you can see, I close my output before to create it in the code, but in the facts, this would never happens because you cannot enter the condition before to create the file.

I can make something dirty, opening a tmp file before my condition, but that's not very elegant. So I was wondering if there is another solution to make Python happy ?

EDIT :

```
if chromosome :
    if chromosome.group(1) != '1' :
        print str(base)+" bases found in chromosome "+chr_name
        chr_name = chromosome.group(1)
    with open(current_dir+"/"+name+"3/"+name+".chr"+chromosome.group(1)+".wig") as output:
        output.write("fixedStep chrom=chr"+chromosome.group(1)+" start=1 step=1\n")
```

EDIT2:

Here is an idea of the algorithm, maybe it could help understand the problem better :

```
for line in input do :
     chromosome = re.search(something)
     if chromosome :
          if chromosome != '1' :
              ouput.close()
          output = open(file+chromosome)
          output.write(title)
     elif somethingElse :
          output.write(somethingElse)
     endif
endfor
```

I want to create different files (file1, file2, file3...). Before to create file2, I have to close file1; before to create file3, I have to close file2; etc...  but for the first one (file1), I don't have to close anything !

Comment: I think you need to give us more context - this is currently looking like an XY problem

Comment: You're right, see EDIT2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for, but I think you could easily solve this with a another nested if statement.

EDIT: too early this morning, forgot this is Python need to have something in the object

```
output = None
    for line in input do :
         chromosome = re.search(something)
         if chromosome :
              if chromosome != '1' :
                  if output != None : 
                       output.close()
              output = open(file+chromosome)
              output.write(title)
         elif somethingElse :
              output.write(somethingElse)
```

Comment: I think it's same. Python will say me that output is not declared in the if you propose.

Comment: Or maybe not.. I will try it.

Comment: Sorry you were right, this is Python, you can get around this by setting the output to Python's version of "null" and checking, when it gets data put into it, it will no longer be "null" or "none" as Python likes to call it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement, like this

```
with open(current_dir+"/"+name+"3/"+name+".chr"+chromosome.group(1)+".wig", 'w') as output:
    output.write("fixedStep chrom=chr"+chromosome.group(1)+" start=1 step=1\n")
```

You don't have to worry about closing the file explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure about this option... because I do not want to close the file before I decided explicitely, because if i close the file then re-open it, I begin to the first line, and I don't want this...

Comment: @spacup With this option, you can remove the `close` function call from your code. This will take care of that

Comment: Yes, it will close the file before I decided it, but my file is not finished to be written because in the rest of the code, I need to fill it.

Comment: @spacup You can write to the file, as long as your code is properly intended within the `with` statement.

Comment: Ah ok. So I will try it and see !

Comment: @spacup Please try that :)

Comment: I have an "Invalid synthax" error... But anyway, I realize that all my code is not included in the with statement... because I use a for loop...

Comment: @spacup Can you please edit your question and post the updated code?

Comment: @spacup Please include the error message, with complete traceback, as well

Comment: The output (if any) follows:

  File "gem2wig.py", line 44
    with open(current_dir+"/"+name+"3/"+name+".chr"+chromosome.group(1)+".wig") as output :
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @spacup What is your python version?

Comment: Python version : 2.4.3

Comment: Same with Python 2.7.5

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this:

```
if chromosome :
    if chromosome.group(1) != '1' :
        print str(base)+" bases found in chromosome "+chr_name
        chr_name = chromosome.group(1)
    else:
        output = open(current_dir+"/"+name+"3/"+name+".chr"+chromosome.group(1)+".wig", 'w')
        output.write("fixedStep chrom=chr"+chromosome.group(1)+" start=1 step=1\n")
        output.close()

        output = open("The next file")
        output.write("whatever")
        output.close()
```

or with improved file handling and `str.format` instead of adding strings:

```
if chromosome :
    if chromosome.group(1) != '1' :
        print str(base)+" bases found in chromosome "+chr_name
        chr_name = chromosome.group(1)
    else:
        with open({}/{}3/{}.chr{}.wig.format(current_dir,name,name,chromosome.group(1), 'w') as output:
            output.write("fixedStep chrom=chr"+chromosome.group(1)+" start=1 step=1\n")
        with open("The next file") as output:
            output.write("whatever")
```

Comment: No, it's much more complex because I want to create various files, not only one. So I want to close the previous one before to create the next one.

Comment: Thanks for your response but my problem is more complicated and enter a bigger script. the problem is that I am parsing a file to create 20 others and I cannot declare all these files as you propose, that's why I included this condition in a loop. Furthermore, I cannot close a file directly after creating it because the parsed file is not finished to be parsed...

Comment: See EDIT2 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a candidate for itertools.groupby:

```
pattern = re.compile(...)
for chromasome, lines in itertools.groupby(input, key=pattern.search):
    with open(filebase + chromosome, 'w') as f:
        for line in lines:
            ...
```